# navigation drawer not opening after next activity finish

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a navigation drawer in my android app, it works fine until I start a new activity, if I start a new activity and then come back to main activity using

```
activity.finish()
```

the navigation drawer doesn't respond anymore to open and close function.

I've implemented my navigation drawer this way:

```
this.mDrawerLayout = context.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
Toolbar toolbar = mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        this.context.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
FrameLayout content_menu = (FrameLayout) this.context.findViewById(R.id.content_menu);
     this.context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sidebar_menu, content_menu, true);
```

And i open the drawer using this functions:

```
private void openMenu(){
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

private void closeMenu(){
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question please .. What exactly are you trying to do.?

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Where do you get `context` from? Why not just use `this`? Is your code from an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: This functions are inside an helper class i've made to reuse around the app the same functions, the context is passed in the constructor

Comment: I think you need to provide some more of your code. Like where are you calling `openMenu()` and `closeMenu()` from? Do they get called? Where are you constructing the helper class instance? Lot's of unknowns, so all we can do is guess what's going on in your particular app.

Comment: Are you closing the main activity?

Comment: I'll improve my question soon

@UmangBurman I'm not closing the current activity but I'm opening a new one

Comment: Alright, Waiting for the question to update.